# Proof Verification - Every sequence in $\Bbb R$ contains a monotone sub-sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, self-learning

Came across the following exercise in *Bartle*'s *Elements of Real Analysis*. This is the solution I came up with. Would be grateful if someone could verify it for me and maybe suggest better/alternate solutions.

I also looked up these related questions - [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668598/problems-with-a-proof-that-every-real-sequence-has-a-monotonic-subsequence), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272153/illustration-proof-that-every-sequence-of-real-numbers-has-monotone-subsequence), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401367/extracting-monotone-distinct-sequence) - but was not happy with proofs given there. I seem to need some help understanding these. Any such help is appreciated.

> Show that every sequence in $\Bbb R$ either has a monotone increasing sub-sequence or a monotone decreasing sub-sequence.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R$. Suppose $(x_n)$ is not bounded. Without loss of generality we may assume that $(x_n)$ is not bounded above. Therefore given any real number there is a member of the sequence which is greater. Let $x_{n_1}$ be any member of the sequence.

There is $x_{n_2} \gt \sup\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n_1} \}$. For $i \gt 1$ let $x_{n_i} = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n_{i - 1}}\}$ then $(x_{n_k})$ forms a monotone subsequence of $(x_n)$.

Now suppose instead that $(x_n)$ is bounded. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem there is a subsequence $(y_n)$ of $(x_n)$ which converges to a limit $y$. Without loss of generality there are infinitely many distinct values in $(y_n)$ that are unequal to $y$. Let $y_{k1}$ be the first such element. Let $y_{k2}$ be any element in $\{ y' \in (y_n) \ \ | \ \ |y' - y | \lt |y - y_{k1}|  \}$.

For $i \gt 1$ let $y_{ki} \in \{ y' \in (y_n)  \ \ | \ \ |y' - y | \lt |y - y_{k \ i - 1}|  \}$. Such $y_{ki}$ exists for every $i \in  \Bbb N$ since $ \lim (y_n) = y $. Now let $(y_{kn})$ be the sub-sequence of $(y_n)$ thus formed. At least one of the two following sets must contain infinitely many elements.

- $\{ y \in (y_{kn}) \ \ | \ \ y \gt x\}$
- $\{ y \in (y_{kn}) \ \ | \ \ y \lt x\}$

The one which does forms a monotone subsequence.

Comment: We do need to worry about increasing versus non-decreasing. Consider the sequence $0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots$.

Comment: @André Nicolas Sorry forgot to mention that. Any sequence of the form $x_1 \le x_2 \le ... x_n \le x_{n + 1} \le ...$ is considered monotone increasing. That's the definition in the book. So that is generally what one would call non-decreasing I believe.

Comment: That's OK with me. So those examples are buried under your second "without loss of generality."

Comment: @André Nicolas: Okay.. Well I've assumed the sequence is not bounded. Based on this there is no loss generality in assuming it is not bounded above. If it is then it is not bounded below and we may construct a decreasing sequence in pretty much the same way. Any issues with this argument??

Comment: Your *second* without loss of generality. The subsequence with limit $y$. There is also an implicit use I think of AC, at least some weak form of it. That's probably fine.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Sorry. Right my reasoning behind that was, if there are only finitely many distinct values in the *convergent* sequence there must be infinitely many elements in the sequence (all $y_n$ for $n \ge m$) which are equal to the limit $y$. This forms a monotone sub-sequence since equality is allowed in our definition of monotony.

Comment: @André Nicolas: AC? As in the Axiom of Choice? Well my knowledge on Set Theory is pitiful. So wouldn't know anything about that.

Comment: It is probable that the book does not worry about the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Doesn't mention it anywhere. And I've had my issues with Set Theory. Have put off learning it for now. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704963/when-should-i-start-learning-set-theory

Comment: By the way, in your bounded part, you need to make the index $k2$ bigger than the index $k1$, and so on.

Comment: @André Nicolas: That is Correct. But that is possible, yes? Need to edit the lines to something like "Let $y_{ki}$ be any element which follows $y_{k i - 1}$ in the sequence $(y_n)$ such that $ |y_{ki} - y | \lt |y - y_{k i - 1}| $. "

Comment: @AndréNicolas Choice is not used here.

Comment: Yes, otherwise what you produce is not a *subsequence*. Foor a subsequence, the $k_i$ must increase.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: True, if at every place where one chooses, one chooses the smallest index that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Exactly. On the other hand, even if the given sequence is recursive, one cannot in general ensure that the monotone subsequence is also recursive.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is a very classic argument, I think. Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be called "nice" if $a_n >a_m$ for all $m> n$.  So we have only two possibilities:

(1) The sequence contains infinitely many "nice" points. If $n_1<n_2<\ldots<n_i< \ldots$ are the "nice" points, we have $a_{n_1}>a_{n_2}> \ldots>a_{n_i}> \ldots$, so $(a_{n_i})$ is a decreasing subsequence.

(2) The sequence contains finitely many "nice" points. Let $n_1$ be greater than all the "nice" points. Since $n_1$ is not "nice" there is some  $n_2>n_1$ such that $a_{n_2}\ge a_{n_1}$, and we continue in this fashion to get a non-decreasing subsequence $(a_{n_i})$.

More formally: Let $N$ be a natural number which is greater than all the "nice" points. We define $n_1:= N$ and $n_{i+1}:=\min\{n> n_{i}: a_n\ge a_{n_{i}}\}$. Hence $(a_{n_i})$ is non-decreasing.

Answer (score 22):

I like to think of this in terms of Ramsey theory. We are coloring the edges of the complete graph on $\mathbb N$, using two colors, and want to ensure that there is a complete infinite subgraph that is monochromatic.

The case that concerns us is the coloring where, for $i<j$, the edge $\{i,j\}$ is colored red if $x_i\le x_j$, and blue otherwise. An infinite monochromatic subgraph gives us the indices of a monotone subsequence: If red, the subsequence is increasing while, if blue, it is strictly decreasing.

Start by noting that there is an infinite $A_0$ with all edges $\{0,i\}$, $i\in A_0$, of the same color. Let $i_0=0$ and $i_1=\min(A_0)$. There is an infinite $A_1\subset A_0$ with all edges $\{i_1,i\}$, $i\in A_1$, of the same color. Let $i_2=\min(A_1)$, and continue this way.

We get $i_0<i_1<\dots$ with the property that, for any $n$, all pairs $\{i_n,i_m\}$ with $m>n$, have the same color. Call it $c_n$. Now, the sequence $c_0,c_1,c_2,\dots$ is a sequence that only takes two values, so it has a constant subsequence. The corresponding $i_n$ form the monochromatic set we were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my knowledge in Graph Theory is restricted to the very basics I am not great with colouring. My question is how do we claim that $A_0$ and $A_1$ contain edges of the same colour? $A_1$ must be infinite but it could contain edges of the opposite colour. So the sequence $i_0, i_1,..$ need not be increasing. Where am I going wrong here??

Comment: The sequence is increasing by construction: $i_0=0$, and $i_{n+1}$ is the minimum of $A_n$. To get $i_{n+2}$ you get inside the rest of $A_n$ (excluding its minimum), so you are automatically dealing only with numbers larger than $i_{n+1}$. You then select an infinite subset $A_{n+1}$ of $A_n$ (according to the prescription in paragraph 3), and then pick $i_{n+2}$ as the minimum of $A_{n+1}$. So, necessarily, the $i_n$ are increasing, we designed them that way.

Answer (score 5):

I think the other proofs are superior, but this is a sketch of the method I came up with when trying to solve it on my own:

If $a_n$ is unbounded, we are done.

Suppose $a_n$ is bounded and let $R_N = \{a_n| n \ge N \}$  (i.e. the range of $a_n$ after $N$). Since $R_N$ is nonempty and bounded, it has a supremum. Note that for every $N$,  $\sup R_{N+1} \le \sup R_N$. Thus if $\forall N \sup R_N$ is a member of the sequence, then we can construct a decreasing subsequence.

Now to finish up, suppose that for some $N$, $x = \sup R_N$ is not a member of the sequence. From the definition of supremum, we know that $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exists an element of the sequence, $a_n$, with $x- \epsilon <a_n$, and we can build an increasing subsequence based on that.

Comment: How we can build the increasing sub-sequence later?

Comment: @Sushil Suppose $x = \sup R_N$ is not a member of the sequence. Let $a_{k_1}$ be a member of $R_N$ with $ |x - a_{k_1}| < 1$. Having chosen $a_{n_k}$, choose $a_{n_{k+1}}$ with $|x - a_{n_{k+1}}| < 1/(k+1)$ and with $a_{k+1} > a_k$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of the proof, which I came up with as an alternative to the much better argument which is peak points:

### **Case 1: Unbounded**

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is unbounded, we have that:
$\forall \ \epsilon \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists \ r \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{such that} \ x_r > \epsilon$

choose $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_f$, we have that: $\exists \ r_1 \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{such that} \ x_{r_1} > \epsilon_f$

Consider: $S_1(n)=\{ x_n \}\backslash\{x_1,x_2,......,x_{r_1}\}$, This is also unbounded, for if it were bounded, the union of $S_1(n)$ with $\{x_1,x_2.....,x_{r_1}\}$ will give me a bounded set, but this contradicts the initial statement that $(x_n)$ is unbounded. Now for this set, choose $ \epsilon_2=x_{r_1}$. Then we have, $\exists \ r_2 \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{such that} \ x_{r_2} > x_{r_1}>\epsilon_f $ and $r_2>r_1$

Consider: $\{ x_n \}\backslash\{x_1,x_2,......,x_{r_1},....,x_{r_2}\}$, This is also unbounded. Now for this set, choose $ \epsilon_3=x_{r_2}$. Then we have, $\exists \ r_3 \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{such that} \ x_{r_3} > x_{r_2}> x_{r_1} > \epsilon_f $ and $r_3>r_2>r_1$. As such, this can be carried on forever to construct a monotone increasing sequence of $x_{r_i}$

### **Case 2: Bounded**

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is bounded. Start by defining the set $S_k =\{ x_n : k \leq n \}$. $S_1=\{x_1,x_2,......\}$, $S_2=\{x_2,x_3,......\}$. We can see that $S_{k+1} \subseteq S_{k}\subseteq....\subseteq S_1$.
These sets $S_i$ are all bounded, and hence they all have supremums, which we can call $Sup(S_{i})=U_{i}$

**Subcase 1: finitely many i $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $U_i \in S_i$**

Suppose the sets $\{ S_{r_1},S_{r_2}....S_{r_p}\}$ contain their own supremum, and the remaining $S_i$ dont contain their supremums. This means that, for $i>r_p$, $U_i=U_{i+1}=U_{i+2}....=U$
to see this, consider $S_i=\{ x_i,x_{i+1},x_{i+2}.....\}$ and $S_{i+1}=\{x_{i+1},x_{i+2}.....\}$ and since none of $x_{j} : j\geq i$ is the supremum of $S_i$, it is clear that none of $x_{j} : j\geq i+1$ is the supremum of $S_{i+1}$

In this case, consider the (infinite) bounded set $S_{r_p+1}=\{x_{r_p+1},x_{r_p+2},....\}$. The supremum of this set is $U$. Hence,
$\exists s_{1} \in S_{r_p+1} \ \text{such that} \ U-\frac{1}{n_1}<s_{1}$

Moreover, $\forall j \in \mathbb{N},\exists s(j) \in S_{r_p+1} \ \text{such that} \ U-\frac{1}{j}<s(j)$

*assertion*:

There exists $n_2 > n_1$ such that $s_{1}<U-\frac{1}{n_2}$

*proof*:

Suppose not, i.e, for a particuar $j$, no matter what $i \in \mathbb{N}$ we use, $s(j) \geq U-\frac{1}{i}$

$\iff \ \forall i \in \mathbb{N} \ s(j)+\frac{1}{i} \geq U$

$\iff \ \lim_{i \to \infty} (s(j)+\frac{1}{i} )=s(j)\geq U$
Which is absurd, hence, assumption is false.

Therefore, for all $j \ \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists i > j : i \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{and} \ s(j) \in S_{r_p+1} \ \text{such that} \ U-\frac{1}{j} < s(j) <U-\frac{1}{i}$

Choose j=1, then:

$\exists i_1 > 1 : i_1 \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{and} \ s_{1} \in S_{r_p+1} \ \text{such that} \ U-1 < s_1 <U-\frac{1}{i_1}$

Choose $j=i_1$ , then:
$\exists i_2 > i_1 : i_2 \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{and} \ s_{2} \in S_{r_p+1} \ \text{such that} \ U-1 < s_1 <U-\frac{1}{i_1} < s_2 <U-\frac{1}{i_2}$

and continue this way, with $j=i_k$ to get $s_{k+1}$, hence forming an infinite sequence of $s_i$ which is monotone increasing.

**Subcase 2: infinitely many $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $U_{i} \in S_i$**

We have that, $\{S_{k_1},S_{k_2},....,S_{k_i}....\}$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$  is an infinite set of $S_i$ such that $U_i \in S_i$

notice then, that, for any $l$ and $r$ $\in \{k_1,k_2.....\}$, $U_l \geq U_r $ if $r>l$. Choose $U_{k+i}=s_{k_i}$, and see that $s_{k_i} \geq s_{k_{i+1}}$, for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. This gives us a monotonic decreasing sequence of $s_i$

Answer (score 1):

**For any converging real sequence, there is a monotone sub-sequence.**

***Proof:***

Let $(x_n)_{n}\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $x_n\rightarrow x$. We assume that $x_n\neq x$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

- As $x$ is a limit point of the sequence, either
  $$\{y:y > x\}\cap  (x_n)_{n} \text{ or } \{y:y < x\}\cap  (x_n)_{n}$$
  contain infinitely many points.
- Assume wlog $X:=\{y:y > x\}\cap  (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ contains infinitely many points. For any $\epsilon > 0$,
  $$
  X \cap [x,x+\epsilon]
  $$
  contains infinitely many points because the sequence converges.
- We can define our sequence $(y_n)_{n}\subset (x_n)_n$ recursively. Choose any $x_k\in X$ and set $y_1 := x_k$. For any $k > 1$ choose
  $$
  y_{k+1} \in X\cap [x,y_{k}].
  $$
  The sequence will be well-defined and decreasing, which is easy to check. As $(y_n)_n\subset X\subset (x_n)_n$, we have constructed the sequence we were looking for.

**For any real sequence, there is a monotone subsequence**.

***Proof:***
Let $(x_n)_n$ be some real sequence.
There are two cases for $(x_n)_n$.

- $(x_n)_n$ is unbounded. In this case we are done, as mentioned in another answer.
- $(x_n)_n$ is bounded by some $K\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $(x_n)_n\cap [-K,K]$ is compact and contains the sequence. By Bolzano-Weierstrass, $(x_n)_n$ contains a converging subsequence. Then by the above proof we are done as well.