# Given a convergent series, can we conclude that the sequence of its terms is monotonic for all $n > N$ for some given $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we are given a convergent series $\Sigma a_n$. Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$. My question is on whether or not we can conclude that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is monotonic for all $n > N$ for some given $N \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: No, they may even change signs now and then. Like $a_n=\sin(n)/n^2$.

Comment: Or $\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$... or every every term whose index corresponds to a multiple of $7$ is zero (take any converging series, add zeros infinitely often)... basically, no. No monotonicity.

Comment: That's a great example.

Comment: Every sequence [has a monotonic subsequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716461/proof-verification-every-sequence-in-bbb-r-contains-a-monotone-sub-sequence), but that's about all you can say in general.

Comment: Consider $0 + 1/2 + 0 + 1/2^2 + 0 + 1/2^3 + 0 + \cdots$

Answer (score 1):

No.  Consider $$a_{n} = {(-1)^n \over n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Other idea : $(-1/2)^n$ or more generally $q^n$ for $-1<q<0$ which oscillates between positive and negative values and tends to 0. Note that this is the general term of a convergent series $$\sum_{n\geq 0} q^n=\dfrac{1}{1-q}$$