# Every sequence of the real numbers has a monotone subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

**I am aware that there are other posts discussing the same proposition. However, I would like to get feedback on my particular solution, which I have not been able to find on the forum. Thank you :)**

---

We can construct a monotone subsequence given any sequence.

We will try to construct two monotone subsequences simultaneously, one increasing and one decreasing. One will be completed, the other will not.

Consider any sequence $(x_n).$

Start the following process with $n = 1$ (the first element in the sequence).

**PROCESS:** Look at $x_n.$ Either there exists an element $x_{n'}$ later in the sequence that satisfies $x_n \leq x_{n'},$ or there does not.

1. If there does not exist such an element after $x_n,$ then all elements $x_{n'}$ after $x_n$ satisfy $x_{n'} < x_n.$ Add $x_n$ as the next element in the monotone *decreasing* sequence. Wipe clean the monotone increasing sequence under construction, and look at $x_{n+1}$ and **start over**.
2. If there does exist such an element $x_{n'}$ after $x_n,$ then add the element as the next element in the monotone *increasing* subsequence. Now, consider $x_{n'},$ and **start over**.

Notice that if there **is** a monotone *increasing* subsequence, then eventually ***Condition 2*** will eventually be everlastingly satisfied and will sequentially construct a monotone *increasing* subsequence.

If there **is no** monotone *increasing* subsequence, every attempt at sequentially constructing a monotone *increasing* sequence will eventually fail, arriving at an peak element $x_p,$ after which there is no element greater or equal to it (that is, there is no element that appears after it in the sequence that satisfies the monotone increasing condition), and ***Condition 1*** will be satisfied infinitely many times, therein sequentially constructing a monotone *decreasing* subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a flaw at this part of the argument:

> Notice that if there **is** a monotone *increasing* subsequence, then eventually ***Condition 2*** will eventually be everlastingly satisfied and will sequentially construct a monotone *increasing* subsequence.

Consider this sequence for $n\geq2$:

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\frac12,-\frac13,\frac14,-\frac15,\frac16,-\frac17,\frac18,-\frac19,\ldots$$

There is a monotonically increasing subsequence: $-\frac13,-\frac15,-\frac17,\ldots$. However, your algorithm fails to find it. Instead, it steps through each value of $n$, wiping clean the increasing sequence under construction at every other step.

I'm not sure whether or not this sort of counterexample completely dooms your "greedy" algorithm, but it's false as stated.

Comment: Hi, Chris. I don't see how it will fail to find that subsequence. Once $\frac{-1}{3}$ is found, it will find $\frac{-1}{5},$  and then $\frac{-1}{7}$ and so on. Notice that condition 2 does specify that the element greater than the current element must be the very next element.

Comment: "Look at $x_n.$ Either there exists an element $x_{n'}$ later in the sequence that satisfies $x_n \leq x_{n'},$ or there does not."

Comment: "If there does exist such an element $x_{n'}$ after $x_n,$ then add the element as the next element in the monotone *increasing* subsequence. Now, consider $x_{n'},$ and **start over**."

Comment: Having arrived at $\frac{-1}{3},$ there will be a later element in the sequence that is greater or equal to $\frac{-1}{3}.$ It will add that element, and then start the process over by looking at that element. And so on

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud It's not a well-defined process if you don't specify any way to know which $n'$ is going to be selected. You might as well write "Let $n'$ be the index that gives me the result I'm hoping for."

Comment: I disagree. That's beside the point. Either there exists one or there doesn't. If there does not, the algorithm proceeds. If there DOES exist one, then select one. It's arbitrary which one that ONE is, as long as it is one of them. It need even be $\frac{-1}{3}, \frac{-1}{5}, ...$ It could be $\frac{-1}{3}, \frac{-1}{9}, ...$

Comment: If you allow the algorithm to select any one that it wants, then it can fail, because it might select $\frac14$. You need some way to prevent that from happening, and it's unclear whether that's possible.

Comment: Chris, it will not select $\frac{1}{4}.$ Notice that condition 2 only works if there exists an element that is greater or equal to it. If there is one (or several), the algorithm specifies to choose one them.

Comment: It selects any one that it wants AMONG the elements that satisfy the condition.

Comment: Start with $x_3=-\frac13$. Does there exist a later element that is greater? Yes, all of them. Choose one of them arbitrarily. Okay, we choose $x_4=\frac14$. Does there exist a later element that is greater? No. Wipe clean and look at $x_5=-\frac15$. Does there exist a later element that is greater? Yes, all of them. Choose one of them arbitrarily. Okay, we choose $x_6=\frac16$. ...

Comment: Fair enough lol.

Comment: I didn't take a closer look at your sequence.

Comment: Nice catch, Chris!

Comment: Thanks, no prob!

Comment: Hey, Chris. Would you mind going over the short proof I attempted for the same proposition below (it was submitted as an answer). Regardless, thanks for your input and patience.

Answer (score 2):

(1). If $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=a$ then $(a_n)_n$ has a monotone sub-sequence $(a_{f(n)})_n.$ Proof:  Let $C=\{n:a_n=a\}.$ Let $P=\{n:a_n>a\}$ and $Q=\{n:a_n<a\}.$

$\quad$ (i). If $C$ is infinite let $f:\Bbb N\to C$ be the unique strictly increasing bijection.

$\quad$ (ii). If $C$ is finite and $P$ is infinite  let $f(1)=\min P$ and let $f(n+1)=\min \{j>f(n):  a< a_j< a_{f(n)}\}.$

$\quad$  (iii). If $S$ and $P$ are finite let  $f(1)=\min Q$ and let $f(n+1)=\min \{j>f(n):a_{f(n)}<a_j<a\}.$

(2). A bounded sequence $(b_n)_n$ has a convergent sub-sequence $(b_{g(n)})_n.$ Proof: Suppose $\{b_n:n\in \Bbb N\}\subset [l,u].$

Let $[l_1,u_1]=[l,u]$ and let $g(1)=1.$

For convenience, for any $n$ let $m_n=(l_n+u_n)/2.$

Now if $\{n:b_n\in [l_n,m_n]\}$ is infinite let $[l_{n+1},u_{n+1}]=[l_n,m_n];$ otherwise let $[l_{n+1},u_{n+1}]=[m_n,u_n].$ And in either case let $g(n+1)=\min \{j>g(n):b_j\in [l_{n+1},u_{n+1}]\}.$

Observe that $|b_{g(n)}-b_{g(n+1)}|\le u_n-l_n=2^{1-n}(u-l)$, which implies that $(b_{g(n)})_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

(3). Let $b_n=\arctan  x_n \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2).$ By (2) there exists a convergent sub-sequence $(b_{g(n)})_n$ and by (1), with $a_n=b_{g(n)},$ the sequence $(b_{g(n)})_n$ has a monotone sub-sequence $(b_{g(f(n))})_n.$ Since $\tan $ is a  monotone function on the domain $(-\pi/2,\pi/2),$ therefore $$(\tan b_{g(f(n))})_n=(x_{g(f(n))})_n$$ is monotone.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed, in essence, the standard proof for this fact.

Comment: Hey Reiner. I couldn't find the proof on math stack exchange (maybe its there, there are many posts discussing this issue). Thanks for you feedback!

Comment: Hi Rafael, see for example http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-monotone-subsequence-theorem or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716461/proof-verification-every-sequence-in-bbb-r-contains-a-monotone-sub-sequence

Comment: That's interesting. I'm surprised it's almost identical to my proof.

Comment: Thanks, Reiner.